# QSortFilterProxyModel how to handle QStandardItems correctly

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have QTreeView with some items and search QLineEdit with connected slot on textEdited signal.
With this code:

```
QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(messagesModel);
proxyModel->setFilterFixedString(text);
ui.treeView->setModel(proxyModel);
```

text filtering is ok, but when I clicked on QTreeView QStandardItems checkboxes (after proxy model assigned to QTreeView), I have the program crashes in slot, that connected to this QTreeView original model (before proxy was assigned).
What is the right way to processing item checkbox clicks? Need I use new connect/slot to processing model changes, or I can use the same code for original model with some changes? I just need to hide filtered items in QTreeView. In QTreeWidget is hide() method, does QTreeView has something like this, or QSortFilterProxyModel - is what I need? Thx!

**UPD** crashed in slot, connected to treeView:

```
auto item = messagesModel->itemFromIndex(index); // item is NULL because proxyModel is set for TreeView now
if(item->whatsThis().isEmpty()) return;    // error below

#ifndef QT_NO_WHATSTHIS
    inline QString whatsThis() const {
        return qvariant_cast<QString>(data(Qt::WhatsThisRole));
    }
    inline void setWhatsThis(const QString &whatsThis);
#endif
```

because I set proxyModel to treeView, but messagesModel have whatsThis...

Comment: you have a crash than show the code which is crashing. If crashed call stack doesn't point to your code, paste this call stack to the question.

Comment: `treeWidget` - is it really QTreeView, or it is QTreeWidget?

Comment: yes. sorry - treeWidget must be QTreeView. code with crash appended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code with that:

```
QStandardItem* item;
if(ui.leFilter->text().isEmpty())
    item = messagesModel->itemFromIndex(index);
else
    item = messagesModel->itemFromIndex(proxyModel->mapToSource(index));
if(item->whatsThis().isEmpty()) return;
```

and it works. Is that correct way? Proxy model is member of my UI class ... not local.

**UPD** how can I update source model when checkbox checked in proxyModel?

**UPD 2** I have load "original" model for QtreeView and show it. When I edit text in QListEdit, I use proxyModel (code from 1st post). When text edited, I have check checkboxes in QtreeView (now proxyModel is active) and at this step all is ok. But when I do some changes in UI, in QTreeView set the original model and it has no changes that was made for proxyModel. How can I notify and update items in source Model with new data from proxyModel?

**UPD3** Yes, source model is also modified ... I have just clear it)

Comment: Can you provide more code or describe more accurately what you want? As i understand, you want to filter your data in model for some string, that's why you use QLineEdit for enter filtering string and set proxy model. Your QStandardItems is checkable. But, i do not understand "how can I update source model when checkbox checked in proxyModel". What do you want? When you check checkbox in QTreeView your QStandartItem check state wiil changed. It is source model. Source model will be updated.